# Python: How can I combine requests and windows certificate store for Client Side Certificates

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, certificate

I'd like to use client side certificates from pythons requests lib (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates) on my windows system.
The cert itself is stored in windows cert store.
What's the best way to access this cert and pass it to requests?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use https://pypi.org/project/wincertstore/ if you like to handle it automatically. or you can manually using `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SystemCertificates`

Comment: Thx. It looks like wincertstore uses CertOpenSystemStoreW from crypt32.dll. However I need to access a certificate from local machine store. That's not supported with CertOpenSystemStoreW (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopensystemstorew#remarks)

So what's the best way to access a certificate in local machine store?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118677/access-windows-local-machine-store-with-python-win32crypt/61141646#61141646