# Access windows local machine store with Python win32crypt

Tags: python, windows, winapi, certificate, pywin32

I'm trying to access a certificate, that's stored in windows local machine store. This can't be done with wincertstore, as it uses CertOpenSystemStoreA function (see remarks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopensystemstorea)

However CertOpenStore from pywin32 has access, I just don't know how to pass the right parameters.
Here's my code:

```
import win32crypt

# store provider
CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM = 13
#dwFlags
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_SERVICE = 0x0100
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER = 0x0200
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER_GROUP_POLICY = 0x0400
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x0800
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE_ENTERPRISE = 0x1000
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE_GROUP_POLICY = 0x2000
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES = 0x4000
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_USERS = 0x8000

store = win32crypt.CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, None, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, "MY")
for cert in store.CertEnumCertificatesInStore():
    print("1 Cert: " + str(cert))
    print("2 CertEnumCertificateContextProperties: " + str(cert.CertEnumCertificateContextProperties()))
    print("3 cert.Subject: " + str(win32crypt.CertNameToStr(cert.Subject)))
```

When running, I get an exception: (-2147024809, 'CertOpenStore', 'Wrong Parameter.')

Documentation of CertOpenStore in pywin32: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32crypt__CertOpenStore_meth.html 
Documentaion of CertOpenStore in Windows Dev Center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up the constants. I don't know where you got them from, but the values (at least both that you used) are wrong, so I deleted them all (didn't look at the others). They (or most of them) are ***preprocessor macros***, defined in [[MS.Docs]: wincrypt.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt) (part of *Windows SDK* - unfortunately I didn't find an **official** location on the web where it could be downloaded from - I have it on my laptop, as it was automatically installed by *Visual Studio*).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import win32crypt as wcrypt


# lpszStoreProvider
CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM = 0x0000000A

# dwFlags
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x00020000


def main(*argv):
    store = wcrypt.CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, None, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, "My")

    for cert in store.CertEnumCertificatesInStore():
        print("1 Cert: {0:}".format(cert))
        print("2 CertEnumCertificateContextProperties returned: {0:}".format(cert.CertEnumCertificateContextProperties()))
        print("3 cert.Subject: {0:}".format(wcrypt.CertNameToStr(cert.Subject)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061118677]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> 1 Cert: <PyCERT_CONTEXT object at 0x0000021CDE3BD740>
> 2 CertEnumCertificateContextProperties returned: [92, 15, 20, 11, 2, 3, 4, 25, 89]
> 3 cert.Subject: localhost
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Just an small addition, here you can see the constants: https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-7/blob/master/v7.1A/Include/WinCrypt.h#L9190 (don't forget to shift them by 16).

Comment: @bgusach: Thanx! Very useful, even if doesn't seem to be the official repo. Personally I have *VStudio* installed, and always look there.